# How to change oauth project title on permissions page

Tags: oauth, google-api

[image]

It shows up "Project Default Service Account" instead of my project name, I see the project name on the google's console but on the permissions page for the given credentials attached to the project name I see that title, weird, anyone knows how to change that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In the Cloud Console Auth section click on Consent Screen and it'll let you edit the look of that page, including the app title and logo.

Comment: (Tiny addition: the link to that page is of the form: https://console.developers.google.com/project/<ProjectNameHere>/apiui/credential )

Comment: At present, the URL form is https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?project=[Project ID]

Comment: Right now its like this : https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?project=<projectname>